# Checking if the checkbox is checked

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, checkbox

How can i check if the `checkbox` is checked or unchecked using a servlet ?

If there are 10 checkboxes in a page then after the user moves forwards to the next page,i need to maintain the check boxes he has checked. Is there a way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

If a checkbox is not checked when you call the Servlet, the request parameter for that checkbox will be null. So you could make sure each checkbox has an individial id on your JSP, and read the values out of the request into a Map with the id as the key when the Servlet is called.

When the user goes back to the page with the checkboxes, pass the values back as request parameters, and use these to set the state of the checkboxes.

If your application is going to get any bigger than this, I'd seriously suggest looking at either:

- JSF2
- Struts
- Spring MVC

Or some other type of Framework. They all support this kind of use case, and they're very easy to get up and running quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSF then you bind each checkbox to a Boolean value in the backing bean.

note. you really need to specify more details about what technologies are you using .... *checkbox* is kind of generic :) but usually  when you say checkbox (checked/unchecked) I thing of a Boolean value to be set true/false.

If you are not tied to java  then you should look for a way to manipulate the DOM. I'll say that the easiest way would be to use jQuery.

Comment: I am not using any technology. There is one HTML page,One Servlet and a Glassfish Server ! Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to do it :

1. You can use various framework that support these functionality like `struts`
2. If you just want to use servlet then you have to save the values of those `checkboxes` in local variable by using `request.getParameter("name_of_checkbox")`. The values can be saved in simple `string` , `array` , `object` or `map`

Comment: _If you just want to use servlet then you have to save the values of those checkboxes in local variable by using request.getParameter("name_of_checkbox"). The values can be saved in simple string , array , object or map_ Can you explain HOW ?

Comment: writing complete code is not possible. however http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/maintain_button/. This article might help you

Comment: article not found. CHECK BEFORE LINKING HERE